# how to protect joomla administrator folder?

Tags: joomla1.6

index.php

```
$admin_cookie_code="1234567890";
setcookie("JoomlaAdminSession",$admin_cookie_code,0,"/");
header("Location: /administrator/index.php");
```

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/administrator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !JoomlaAdminSession=1234567890
RewriteRule .* - [L,F]
```

i used this code but it's not working...
page will be redirect to administrator but www.domain.com/administrator is also accessable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got tired of searching an answer for this one and just made a PHP code that will redirect if the visitor gets into the /administration folder without the security key or as a registered user:

Just place this code at the end of the index.php file on your administration folder (/administration/index.php) before the 'echo' instruction:

```
/* Block access to administrator
 --------------------------------------------- */
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$secretkey = 'mysecretkey';
$redirectto = 'location: yourdomainurlhere';
$usertype = 'Registered';

//Check if the user is not logged in or if is not a super user:
if ($user->guest || (!$user->guest && $user->usertype != $usertype) ) {
 //Check if the secret key is present on the url:
 if (@$_GET['access'] != $secretkey) { header($redirectto); }
}
/* --------------------------------------------- */
```

After you will be only able of accessing your site using:
mysite.com/administrator/?access=mysecretkey

Tested on Joomla 1.5 and Jooma 2.5, worked well for both.

I explain it a little bit more on my page:
https://www.infoeplus.com/protect-your-joomla-administrator-folder/

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to hide the administrator URL ? Here is what I'm using :
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection/15711

You can find more extensions here : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection

Answer (score 1):

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection

you can use this protect your admin login.
this is really esay and nice extension.